# Removing weekend days from calendar with proper data placement

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

I am trying to use the script for "Removing weekend days from calendar" as outline in [this string](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/83372/removing-weekend-days-from-calendar/165077#165077).

But, while the two columns are removed from the calendar(s) on the page, the actual data does not line up correctly with the columns. Here is a screen shot of what I'm seeing...
[image: less columns, but data not lined up]

Are there any suggestions on how to tweak the code for proper placement?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

var oTable = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
if (oTable != null) {

for (i = 0; i < oTable.length; i++)
{
var table = oTable.item(i);
if (table.className == "ms-acal-month")
{
for (var c = 0; c < table.rows.length; c++)
{
if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 8)
{
table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
table.rows[c].cells[1].style.display = "none";
table.rows[c].cells[7].style.display = "none";
}
else if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 7)
{
table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
table.rows[c].cells[6].style.display = "none";
}
else if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 6)
{
table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
table.rows[c].cells[5].style.display = "none";
}
else if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 2)
{
table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
table.rows[c].cells[1].style.display = "none";
      }
     }
    }
   }
  } 
});
function month(){

var oTable = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
if (oTable != null) {

for (i = 0; i < oTable.length; i++)
{
var table = oTable.item(i);
if (table.className == "ms-acal-month")
{
for (var c = 0; c < table.rows.length; c++)
{
if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 8)
{
table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
table.rows[c].cells[1].style.display = "none";
table.rows[c].cells[7].style.display = "none";
}
else if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 7)
{
table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
table.rows[c].cells[6].style.display = "none";
}
else if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 6)
{
table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
table.rows[c].cells[5].style.display = "none";
}
else if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 2)
{
table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
table.rows[c].cells[1].style.display = "none";
}

     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
 //For week view
 function week(){

var oTable = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
if (oTable != null) {

for (i = 0; i < oTable.length; i++)
{
var table = oTable.item(i);
if (table.className == "ms-acal-detail")
{
for (var c = 0; c < table.rows.length; c++)
{
if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 8)
{
table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
table.rows[c].cells[1].style.display = "none";
table.rows[c].cells[7].style.display = "none";
}
else if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 7)
{
table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
table.rows[c].cells[6].style.display = "none";
}
else if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 6)
{
table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
table.rows[c].cells[5].style.display = "none";
}
else if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 2)
{
table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
table.rows[c].cells[1].style.display = "none";
}

     }
    }
   }
  }
 }



$( "#WPQ2_nav_prev_a" ).click(function() {
 month();
})
$( ".ms-picker-table" ).click(function() {
month();
})
$( "#WPQ2_nav_next_a" ).click(function() {
month();
})
setInterval(function () { month()}, -10000);
setInterval(function () { month()}, -10000);
setInterval(function () { week()}, -10000);

 </script>
```

Comment: Well, this code just hides two columns from the calendar table, but the actual events (blue bars) do not live inside the table. The events live inside a div that has `class="ms-acal-rootdiv"`. Because of this, the formatting of the table (that is now missing two columns) is different from the formatting of the events. I quickly had a look how to reformat the events, but it seems like a lot of work to do. I suggest looking for a different way of doing this using **JSOM** and the **SP.UI.ApplicationPages.Calendar.js** SharePoint JS library.

Comment: If you know some JavaScript, [this article](http://josharepoint.com/2014/12/01/expand-all-events-by-default-on-sharepoint-2013-calendars/) may be a good start to get to what you are trying to do. I have not been able to a solution to exactly what you need and I unfortunately do not have time right now to write the code for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the same exact code, but use `visibility: hidden` instead of `display: none`

```
table.rows[a].cells[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
```

display:none will shift the css to remove the white space, but it looks as though the layover thinks the weekends are still there...